# ETH address under OP Network

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core

we mistakenly transfer USDT to our ETH address but under OP Network, after having a chat with help center, they first provided loom video to recreate Safe Wallet address under OP network, which we did,and afterwards we are able to see our funds in dashboard, but not able to transfer the funds to another wallet or bridge. We tried everything, like clearing browser and using different browser. It is now asking asking to use Safe CLI to execute the transaction, which safe help center also confirms.

I am non-tech person and don't know how to use Safe CLI, Devs - can you please help on this.

Recreated SafeWallet address - oeth:0x3ff1034abFfACf98b71d38A814B00b997E8fc99f

Thanks and Regards
Akash

Answer (score 0):

There will be a few steps to follow:

1. Open a terminal

If you use a Mac, you can open a terminal by pressing CMD + Space (to open the command palette), and then type "terminal.app". If you are running on Windows, you will need first to install the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install), and then run `wsl.exe` from the Windows command prompt.

2. Install CLI

```
pip3 install -U safe-cli
```

3. Load Safe

You will need to create an account on infura.io and then load your Safe into the CLI:

```
safe-cli 0x3ff1034abFfACf98b71d38A814B00b997E8fc99f https://optimism-mainnet.infura.io/v3/YOUR-API-KEY
```

Then, load all the current owners of the safe (two in this case):

```
load_cli_owners <PRIVATE KEY FOR OWNER 1>
load_cli_owners <PRIVATE KEY FOR OWNER 2>
```

4. Create the transfer transaction:

Let's try transfering a few tokens first. Replace `NUMBER OF TOKENS TO SEND` with, let's say, `10`:

```
send_erc20 <ADDRESS THAT WILL RECEIVE THE TOKENS> 0x94b008aA00579c1307B0EF2c499aD98a8ce58e58 <NUMBER OF TOKENS TO SEND>
```

If everything works well, you can try again this step but with all the remaining tokens.

For more information, you can find all instructions and reference for `safe-cli` [here](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-cli).

Please let me know if it worked!