# Need help to transfer back a wrong sent token (USDT)

Tags: safe-core

This is my  wallet address:
0x34aec52df8f2a59167ce37f7c4dde17b8d58d4dd
It is from Polymarket: https://polymarket.com

Polymarket works with Polygon and I am supposed to send there ONLY USDC
Now I made a mistake and sent USDT (on the Polygon Chain) to this wallet. …10,100 USDT… Big money for me…

I need to send it back now to my origin wallet, which is
0x9dfaaeb3281e6cceaabca3b7720ad7abbc24ae6b

I see the USDT already on app.save.global
https://app.safe.global/home?safe=matic:0x34aec52DF8f2A59167cE37f7c4dDe17b8d58D4dd
but with a Ethereum sign… and I see also this error message:

This transaction will most likely fail. To save gas costs, avoid confirming the transaction. Details
This Safe Account was created with an unsupported base contract. It should ONLY be used for fund recovery. Transactions will execute but the transaction list may not immediately update. Transaction success can be verified on the

The hotline told me:
So since this is a replayed Safe, this is normal behavior that it won't work properly in the interface. Mainnet and L2/Sidechains Safes use a slightly different contract, so they are incompatible with our UI/backend out of the box.
You'll need to manage the replayed Safe using Safe CLI instead https://github.com/gnosis/safe-cli

But unfortunately I am not a Dev… And I really don’t know how to do this wht is written on
https://github.com/gnosis/safe-cli
I hope you can help me…

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the instructions I provided to someone having a similar issue here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/159473/127930

Hope it helps,
Louis